# How can I make the transition between routes scrolling?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to make the transition between routs not only links, but also scrolls. Who faced this, please tell me. Maybe someone saw a similar example?

P.S. I'm new to the react.js

Can eat other ways to implement this? react routes + scrollUp/scrollDown

```
<div className="content">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route path="/partners" component={Partners} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
 </div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but it does not work out

```
 <Route path={this.props.history.push(url)} component={About} />
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: React full-page custom option, go to the next or previous router with a scroll

Comment: what are you using react native or react js??

Comment: I'm using react.js

Comment: Add proper tags next time!

Comment: @RaajNadar help me please

Comment: Can you put up a live demo of what you have right now??

Comment: @RaajNadar yes, with which program?

Comment: With the code that is not working need a fiddler to check what is wrong!

Comment: @RaajNadar https://codepen.io/maxnag/pen/YagvwV?editors=0010 I need to make a jump on the routes with the scroll wheel of the mouse

Comment: You want to move from home to about on scroll right?? It seems very tough

Comment: @RaajNadar I need to scroll down to the next page, scroll up the previous router

Comment: @RaajNadar hi, you heard about `withRouter` ?

Comment: The thing is I never used routing with react js, I always made single page app.

Comment: Why use a router if you do not change pages ? You want to do two things different the same way, which is not easily doable.
You can always listen to the scroll event and when you reached the number of pixel you want, you use the router to push a new url, which should load the page you want.

Comment: @ChrisR Thank you, help me deal with this code [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814842/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-scroll-in-react]